# How to get rid off default classes applied by ngbootstrap

Tags: css, angular, ng-bootstrap

I use ngbootstrap for popovers, but I want to override all the default styles it comes with. I have a form that should be displayed as a popover on a button click which has its own styles.

When I use [ngbPopover] it renders an element with the default class of 'popover' applied, instead of overriding each of its properties to align with my expectation, is it possible to remove it all together while rendering on the page and then I could use a custom class with popoverClass property.

```
<ng-template #popContent><user-form></user-form></ng-template>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-secondary" [ngbPopover]="popContent">
  I've got markup and bindings in my popover!
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking into [the popover source code](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/popover/popover.ts#L41) I see lots of classes nailed without a chance to change them. I suppose the only promising approach would be exclude the css for the popover component from the import.
How to do it depends on how you import the Bootstrap css